# Xcode becomes unresponsive when collecting view hierarchy

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode11

When I run my app and then try to get the debug view hierarchy for my app Xcode immediately becomes unresponsive (it does pause the app but then becomes unresponsive). I've tried deleting derived data, restarting the simulator and Xcode, and downloaded and tested from my own phone. I even re-installed Xcode and I still have the same problem. What could this be? Is it just an incredibly frustrating bug in Xcode 11? Is there any way I can solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has this problem: I got it to work by re-installing Mac OS.

Comment: I know it late to comment but I think this is not the best solution, if you find another way please update your answer to help others.